# Angular Observable for PDFJS metadata extraction

Tags: angular, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to extract metadata from a PDF using PDFJS and get it via an Observable subscription.

Code of the service:

```
export interface PdfProperties {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  subject: string;
  keywords: string;
}

...

  extractPdfProperties(file: Uint8Array): any {
    const pdfPropertiesObservable = new Observable<PdfProperties>( (observer) => {

      const pdfLoading = pdfjsLib.getDocument(file);
      pdfLoading.promise.then( pdf => {
        pdf.getMetadata().then( metadata => {
          this.pdfProperties.title = metadata.info.Title;
          this.pdfProperties.author = metadata.info.Author;
          this.pdfProperties.keywords = metadata.info.Keywords;
          this.pdfProperties.subject = metadata.info.Subject;
          observer.next(this.pdfProperties);
          return this.pdfProperties;
          });
        });
    });
    return pdfPropertiesObservable;
  }
```

Code of the component

```
 onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const typedArray = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as Uint8Array);
      const pdfObservable$ = this.pdfProperties.extractPdfProperties(typedArray);
      pdfObservable$.subscribe((subscriptionpdfp: PdfProperties) => { this.pdfp = subscriptionpdfp; });

    };
  }
```

There is no error, but this.pdfp keeps being undefined.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually creating an observable, you could use RxJS [`from`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) function to convert the promise to an observable. From there you could apply any of the RxJS operators to convert the response notification to the form you require.

I am using [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to map from one observable to another and [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator to transform the notification to an object of instance type `PdfProperties`.

Try the following

```js
export interface PdfProperties {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  subject: string;
  keywords: string;
}

extractPdfProperties(file: Uint8Array): Observable<PdfProperties> {    // <-- return an observable
  return from(pdfjsLib.getDocument(file).promise).pipe(   // <-- convert promise to an observable
    switchMap(pdf => from(pdf.getMetadata())),    // <-- switch to `getMetadata()` promise
    map(metadata => ({                            // <-- map to object of interface type `PdfProperties`
      title: metadata['info']['Title'],
      author: metadata['info']['Author'],
      keywords: metadata['info']['Keywords'],
      subject: metadata['info']['Subject']
    } as PdfProperties))
  );
}

onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(input.files[0]);
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    const typedArray = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as Uint8Array);
    this.pdfProperties.extractPdfProperties(typedArray).subscribe((subscriptionpdfp: PdfProperties) => {
      this.pdfp = subscriptionpdfp;
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the type of metadata in map should be specified, or it will complain that does not know the "info" bit. (Property 'info' does not exist on type 'unknown'.). Do you know what type is that ?

Comment: That's most probably a TS Lint error. The code should work fine nevertheless. It is showing that error because the Linter has no knowledge about the properties of the response from `getMetadata()` call. You could quickly fix it by using bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the properties. I've updated the answer. Another way would be to define an interface for the response signature from the `getMetadata()` function and define the type of the `metadata` variable.